Amazon SP-API - get configurable products
I checked all types of "Inventory" reports (https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/report-type-values-inventory) and none of them return information about whether the product is configurable or not. I really need to be able to check if product is set as configurable or not. Can I get this product information in another way?

I'm sorry, but if you are referring to Amazon Custom products, these informations are not available as far as I know.
The only way we get information about them is through orders' reports, by checking either CustomizedUrl or CustomizedPage properties on each Item property of an Order. In this case, remember to enable these customization columns inside the "Customize order columns" section in Orders > Reports on Seller Central.
